# How to get the values from an extended class in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am creating a command-line app where it reads what the user puts in and then makes a POST request with that data (I've just started).

My problem is I've never seen a class extended like this before and it's throwing me off. How do I get the values from CommandApp so that I can use it in my Main Object?

```
import cats.implicits._
import com.monovore.decline._


object Main extends CommandApp(name = "hello-world",
  header = "Says hello!",
  main = {
    val userOpt = Opts.option[String]("target", help = "Person to greet.").withDefault("world")

    val quietOpt = Opts.flag("quiet", help = "Whether to be quiet.").orFalse

    (userOpt, quietOpt).mapN { (user, quiet) =>
      if (quiet) println("...")
      else println(s"Hello $user!")
    }
  }) {


  // How do I get the value from user into here.
  // Eventually I will want to use that user data variable for a POST request.


}
```

Comment: I'm just getting started with this library http://ben.kirw.in/decline/ . I am trying to get the value of user.

Comment: Don't you have the values inside the `mapN`?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly you want to pattern match the case class Parameters of `CommandApp` from the main Object?

In Scala this isn't directly possible since Main is a child of CommandApp and not the other way round (you can only pattern match to child case classes). But you can use traits:

1. Declare a new Trait that has no direct function
2. CommandApp has to inherit that trait
3. Convert your main Object to that trait type
4. Pattern matching

Since i don't have your class definitions, i wrote a small example. Let's say your class looks like this:

```
case class Test(str:String)
class MainTest extends Test("Hello World!")
```

and you want to access the `str` value of Test like this:

```
val t = new MainTest()
t match{
     case Test(str) => println(str)
     case _ => println("Could not match")
}
```

This would not work since MainTest is not a case class and therefore cannot be pattern matched. But if you declare a new trait which Test inherits:

```
trait InheritanceTrait
case class Test(str:String) extends InheritanceTrait
class MainTest extends Test("Hello World!")
```

You can pattern match a MainTest object by casting it to a InheritanceTrait, which has a pattern-matching child class (therefore can be pattern matched):

```
val t = new MainTest()
t.asInstanceOf[InheritanceTrait] match{
    case Test(str) => println(str)
    case _ => println("Could not match")
} //prints "Hello World!"
```

If you don't want to or simply can't declare a super class of `CommandApp` you could use a dirty alternative by converting `t` to the `Any` type, since every class inherits from Any. Would work just as fine.

My example then would like this:

```
object Main{
    case class Test(str:String)
    class MainTest extends Test("Hello World!")

    def main(args:Array[String]){
        val t = new MainTest()
        t.asInstanceOf[Any] match{
            case Test(str) => println(str)
            case _ => println("Could not match")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this solved your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it is really useful. See where I do println(user) if I changed that to user. How would I get that user value into the main class?

Comment: That wont be possible except if you modify CommandApp with an additional Attribute in which you could store that value , since the user value is inside a lambda and therefore a local variable which cannot be accessed by basic pattern matching.

(Of course storing this variable statically would be possible but that would not be a nice solution)

Answer (score -2):

It should be noted that `CommandApp` isn't a case class, it's a regular `abstract class`.

The intended use of `CommandApp` appears to be that your entire program goes into `main` and when `main` completes, your program is done.  This is evidenced by the class having a name ending in `App` (c.f. `IOApp`) and has `main`.

So what you would do is define a function elsewhere which takes whatever values you've validated that you want to use (e.g `user` in this case) as arguments and does stuff with them, e.g.

```
// Disclaimer: I'm guessing from the code that userOpt is Option[String]
def sendUserAsPostRequest(user: String): Unit = {
  // sending the user as a POST is left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

You can place that function in `Main` or in a different object (or in a different class as long as your `main` constructs an instance of that class).  You're main would then look like (I'm assuming that for this, you're not interested in `quiet`):

```
main = {
  val userOpt = Opts.option[String]("target", help = "Person to greet.").withDefault("world")

  userOpt.map(sendUserAsPostRequest)
}
```